# How to read WKB using JTS WKBReader when input bytestream contains SRID in it?

Tags: jts

The [documentation](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/io/WKBReader.html) for WKBReader says:

> It also partiually handles the Extended WKB format used by PostGIS (by
>   reading SRID values)

but when I pass a byte array that has an SRID in the first 4 bytes to `WKBReader` I get an exception from `WKBReader`. [This](http://www.dev-garden.org/2011/11/27/loading-mysql-spatial-data-with-jdbc-and-jts-wkbreader/) link also runs into same issue and skips the first 4 bytes before passing the byte stream to `WKBReader`. Looking at the code itself for `WKBReader`:

```
private Geometry readGeometry() throws IOException, ParseException {
        byte byteOrderWKB = this.dis.readByte();
        int byteOrder = byteOrderWKB == 1?2:1;
        this.dis.setOrder(byteOrder);
        int typeInt = this.dis.readInt();
        int geometryType = typeInt & 255;
        boolean hasZ = (typeInt & -2147483648) != 0;
        this.inputDimension = hasZ?3:2;
        this.hasSRID = (typeInt & 536870912) != 0;
        int SRID = 0;
        if(this.hasSRID) {
            SRID = this.dis.readInt();
        }
```

It looks incorrect as it doesn't decode first 4 bytes as SRID. I also tried following:

```
g = some JTS Geometry
g.setSRID(4326);
new WKBReader().read(new WKBWriter().write(g)).getSRID()
```

returns `0` instead of expected `4326`. My question is could anyone from JTS confirm that this is indeed a bug? If not, what is wrong? It would be good to have it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: This is not a bug. `WKBReader` supports SRID in `WKBWriter`'s format.

```
new WKBReader().read(new WKBWriter(2, true).write(g)).getSRID();
```

returns expected answer. This method signature is not present in official [docs](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/io/WKBWriter.html) but is present [here](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/io/WKBWriter.html).